# JS in HTML gets stuck on if statements

Tags: javascript, html

My objective is to create a web game where a country name is given and the user must enter the correct capital of that country. A new row is then inserted with the country and answer and whether it's correct and a new country is shown. I have both the random country selector and insert new row working when I press the button with the id of "pr2__submit".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YourName 20200000</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./capital_game.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bakbak+One&family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 850px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D3D3D3;
    }

  </style>

  </head>

  <body>
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./country_capital_pairs.js"></script>
  <script src="./capital_game.js"></script>
    <!--Your HTML here-->
    <h1 style="font-size:70px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Bakbak One', cursive;"  >Name the capital <i class="far fa-flag"></i></h1>
    <script>
    function randomCountry(){
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length);
    document.getElementById("pr2__question").innerHTML = pairs[x].country;
    let y = pairs[x].capital;
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function focusInput() {
    document.getElementById("pr2__answer").focus();
    document.getElementById("pr2__answer").value = "";
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function newRow() {
    let guess = document.getElementById("pr2__answer").value;
    
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var row = table.insertRow(2);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
    break;
    
      }
    </script>

    <table id="myTable" style="font-size:200%;" class="center">
      <tr style="border-bottom: 3px solid #330066; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;">
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="pr2__question"></td>
        <td><input id="pr2__answer" type="text" placeholder="Your answer" autofocus><br></td>
        <td> <button id="pr2__submit" onclick="newRow(); randomCountry(); focusInput();">See Answer</button> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="lastQuestion"></td>
        <td id="lastAnswer">No entry to show</td>
        <td id="correctAnswer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
    randomCountry();
    </script>


    <script>
     var inputText = document.getElementById("pr2__answer");
     inputText.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           event.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById("pr2__submit").click();
        }
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to add an if statement to determine whether the correct answer was input it does not work, and the random country selector and and insert new row stop working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YourName 20200000</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./capital_game.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bakbak+One&family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 850px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D3D3D3;
    }

  </style>

  </head>

  <body>
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./country_capital_pairs.js"></script>
  <script src="./capital_game.js"></script>
    <!--Your HTML here-->
    <h1 style="font-size:70px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Bakbak One', cursive;"  >Name the capital <i class="far fa-flag"></i></h1>
    <script>
    function randomCountry(){
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length);
    document.getElementById("pr2__question").innerHTML = pairs[x].country;
    let y = pairs[x].capital;
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function focusInput() {
    document.getElementById("pr2__answer").focus();
    document.getElementById("pr2__answer").value = "";
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function newRow() {
    let guess = document.getElementById("pr2__answer").value;
    if (guess === y) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var row = table.insertRow(2);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
    break;
    }
      }
    </script>

    <table id="myTable" style="font-size:200%;" class="center">
      <tr style="border-bottom: 3px solid #330066; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;">
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="pr2__question"></td>
        <td><input id="pr2__answer" type="text" placeholder="Your answer" autofocus><br></td>
        <td> <button id="pr2__submit" onclick="newRow(); randomCountry(); focusInput();">See Answer</button> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="lastQuestion"></td>
        <td id="lastAnswer">No entry to show</td>
        <td id="correctAnswer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
    randomCountry();
    </script>


    <script>
     var inputText = document.getElementById("pr2__answer");
     inputText.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           event.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById("pr2__submit").click();
        }
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does `newRow()` have a `break` statement that's not in a loop?

Comment: `y` is a local variable in the `randomCountry()` function. You need to make it a global variable so you can refer to it in `newRow()`.

Comment: you haven't declared what `pairs` is